# Difference between ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream and getClass().getResourceAsStream()

Tags: java

Given this code:

```
/* 1 */ InputStream in1 = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("foobar.txt");
/* 2 */ InputStream in2 = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/foobar.txt");
```

Do both return the same resource (I think the answer's "yes")?

Do they both access the "same" classpath?  Why is the method name in #1 "get **System** ResourceAsStream", but for #2 it's just "getResourceAsStream"?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the javadoc

> Open for reading, a resource of the specified name from the search
>   path used to load classes. This method locates the resource through
>   the system class loader (see [getSystemClassLoader()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader%28%29)).

The classloader used to load `this` is not necessarily the system classloader. In a simple desktop app, this will probably be true. But webapps - amongst other things - typically have more complex classpath hierarchies and so that won't necessarily be the same. In a complex classpath, therefore what's returned will also depend on how many copies of 'foobar.txt' are floating around your classpath.

The short answer is that you can't assume that they will return a stream for the same resource.

Comment: So you're saying there are multiple classpaths in web applications?

Comment: @Michael - Sort of. Typically, each webapp gets its own classloader which is responsible for the contents of the WAR, EAR, etc. These classloaders have a common parent and so classes in common lib directories are shared between the various webapps. But these hierarchies can be several loaders deep. The system classloader will be at the top, but there maybe a number in between.

Comment: Different webapps will probably have different classloaders.  For instance, in Glassfish, they have a hierarchy specified here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/6nmndgmhr/index.html#fvxzq.

Answer (score 12):

The key difference is the class loader.

The following uses the System ClassLoader
    `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("foobar.txt");`

While this one uses the Classloader returned by `getClass()`
    `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/foobar.txt");`

In other words, whether both statements behave exactly the same or not, depends on the application classloader. For a simple application, both refer to the same classloader. However, for most applications (like a web application running within Servlet container), that will not be the case.

In general, I would say getClass().getResourceAsStream() will be the better choice as it will use the same classloader as the Class the code belongs to.